# Sort data by two alternating categories

Tags: excel

I want to sort my data into two categories that are supposed to alternate, so that the order is 1,0,1,0,1,0,...

I already have a whole dataset and the categories 1 and 0 are mixed. (e.g. 1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,...) I want to sort the data set so that 1 and 0 alternate

How can I do this? Could not find out how to.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear! I already have a whole dataset and the categories 1 and 0 are mixed. (e.g. 1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,...) I want to sort the data set so that 1 and 0 alternate

Comment: Are there other entries in your row? Do you want to preserve order as much as possible?

Comment: Yes, there is more information in the rows that is important and should be preserved.

Comment: [This](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=185294) shows how to do an alternating sort on 'M,F' using a helper column. It's about a three step process, easily converted to '1,0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste below formula to cell **D2**, then drag down to copy. When sorted by **D** column we will have **binary** column sorted as 0,1,0,1... etc.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A11,A2)+A2/10
```

[image]

Or we can use below as suggested by @DirkReichel:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)+A2/2
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense using something like `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)+A2/2`? it would be in an ascending order and no cells below the last entry would be counted (this would avoid various other errors)... and it would be noticeable faster specifically at bigger tables